# How to return List<Long> value from method in java and put it in new list?

Tags: java

I have in one java class a method which `SELECT` one coloumn from a table from my database, and that column is an `INT` type in the database, and then I select items from that coloumn, put it in a List and return this List. Here is the method:

```
 public List<Long> vratiSveSifreRacuna() throws SQLException {
        String sqlVratiSifruRacuna = "SELECT RacunID FROM racun";

        Statement stat = konekcija.createStatement();
        ResultSet  rs  = stat.executeQuery(sqlVratiSifruRacuna);

        Long racunID = 0L;
        List<Long> sifre = new ArrayList<Long>();

        while (rs.next()){
          racunID = rs.getLong("RacunID");
          sifre.add(racunID);
        }
        return sifre;
    }
```

Now, how can I return a list from this method and put in another list?
When I try to do it, it doesn`t work...like it sees the returned list empty or something...
Why is that happenning? Is this method ok?
 I want to have a method which returns a whole coloumn from from a database table as List and then I want to use this List somehow...

Comment: This might sound stupid but.. your query does return something right?

Comment: You used getLong for an INT column

Comment: Well, if you add the list that was returned from this method ... and you find that returned list to be empty ... did you verify that your query works; and that it finds data?

Comment: @cricket_007 So even when that method is wrong, the above code would add whatever getLong() returns; so, worst case, it would generate a list of nulls or so.

Comment: Yes I used getLong for INT coloumn but earlier when I did the same it worked...If it is other way round, if I tried to put Long elements in INT List, it would be logic that it doesn`t work but long is bigger than int so that would be ok...                                                                                                     I am not realy sure does my query return something...But I don`t see reason why it should not...How can I verify that? How to verify does this query works?

Comment: I actually think that that my code just generate list of nulls....But how to fix this?

Comment: Hint: dont put more information into comments; update your question instead.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you have an INT value in your database and you're using `getLong()` to try and get an INT value which is probably why it's not working.

Try to use this instead:

```
while (rs.next()){
      racunID = (Long) rs.getInt("RacunID");
      sifre.add(racunID);
}
    return sifre;
```

EDIT 1 (Simplified) :

```
while (rs.next()){
      sifre.add(new Long(rs.getInt("RacunID")));
}
    return sifre;
```

Comment: Man you are boxing an int result into a Long which again gets unboxed when getting assigned to racunID, then it will again get autoboxed when being put into the list. too many unnecessary operations

Comment: no need to box into Long in short ;) if anything, do (long)

Comment: See it again. Is it like that?

Comment: It don`t permit me to do like this, it says: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Long...

Comment: Now there is no errors in code, it can compile but still it sees the list empty...

Comment: Try debugging your code. See if the query returns any results. If it doesn't the problem is there now that we know that the list is being created correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to add to a new List, just pass your original list along in parameters:

```
public void vratiSveSifreRacuna(List<Long> passedList) throws SQLException {
    String sqlVratiSifruRacuna = "SELECT RacunID FROM racun";

    Statement stat = konekcija.createStatement();
    ResultSet  rs  = stat.executeQuery(sqlVratiSifruRacuna);

    Long racunID = 0L;
    List<Long> sifre = passedList;

    while (rs.next()){
      racunID = rs.getInt("RacunID"); //column is int, it will automatically upcast to long don't worry about that
      sifre.add(racunID);
    }

    //set sifre to null now to let it get garbage collected :)
    sifre=null
}
```

Call the method as follows now:

```
yourclassreference.vratiSveSifreRacuna(yourListLong);
```

Comment: also since your column is INT , use getInt()

Comment: Thanks for answering but it still doesn`t work, I don`t know why, it can`t do this line of code properly: yourclassreference.vratiSveSifreRacuna(yourListLong);

Answer (score 0):

Keep your method as it is (side-effects on parameters should be avoided).

Call the method, store the result, and add it to the other list you want to complete.

```
List<Long> foo = ...; // i don't know where it comes from
List<Long> bar = vratiSveSifreRacuna();
foo.addAll(bar);
```

See [java.util.List#addAll API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: I`m not sure if I understand you right...What should I write in this first line of yours, List<Long> foo = new ArrayList(); or something like that...When I do like this and then do the other two line you wrote, it still doesn`t work...